# Laravel 5 Model::with() behavior

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm trying to get a simple list of products with a given category, using Laravel 5's (L5) Model::with() method. But it seems that L5 ignores the category where clause.

The relation in my Product model:

```
public function categories(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category', 'categories_products');
}
```

In my Controller:

```
public function getByCategory($slug){
    $return = Product::with(array('categories' => function($query) use ($slug){
        $query->where('slug', 'like', $slug);
    }))->paginate(60);
    dd($return);
}
```

The result is a list of every product in my database, instead of just a list of those with the given category slug.

I'v tried to hardcode in some different where clauses, but all seems to be ignored. Am I missing something?

Comment: I am not familiar with laravel. But, you can use Xdebug to debug this. Sure, this will help you a lot . For Xdebug configuration, You can go with this link http://blog.thecodingmachine.com/content/setting-xdebug-debugging-environment-php-wamp-eclipse-pdt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eloquent doesn't use joins to query related data when using with(), but instead uses separate queries.  In your example, it first fetches products and then fetches related categories.

You need to use [`has()` or `whereHas()`](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#querying-relations) to return only those products that have categories (slugs?).

```
public function getByCategory($slug){
    $return = Product::has('categories')->with(array('categories' => function($query) use ($slug){
        $query->where('slug', 'like', $slug);
    }))->paginate(60);
    dd($return);
}
```

Or:

```
public function getByCategory($slug){
    $return = Product::whereHas('categories', function($query) use ($slug){
        $query->where('slug', 'like', $slug);
    })->paginate(60);
    dd($return);
}
```

whereHas() adds a subquery that counts the number of relations.  You should use DB::getQueryLog() to see the SQL that Eloquent produces.  Makes it a lot easier to figure out what's going on!

Comment: The second example seems to give the result I want, thanks. Though it is really (and I mean really) slow! But I'll mark it as an answer nevertheless.

Comment: Your first paragraph should be included in the official docs regarding eager load.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to have an advanced subquery?  If slug is defined as a column in product you can do this:

```
$return = Product::where('slug', 'like', $slug)->paginate(60);
dd($return);
```

Or if using the relations your query would look like this:

```
$return = Product::where('slug', 'like', $slug)->categories->paginate(60);
dd($return);
```

Comment: Your first example will only list products with the given slug (I assume), and not the categories with that given slug (which is what I want). And the second example results in an ErrorException "Non-static method App\Product::categories() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context"

Comment: Per your question: I am trying to get a simple list of products with a given category.  My second one was off... whoops, I'm not sure if thats entirely right either, but worth a shot.

Comment: Emphasising: "with a given category". Meaning: I have a category slug, and I would like a list of products, whom is related to categories with that given slug.

Comment: Are you meaning you want a list of products and you want their categories to be joined in (so you can retrieve the columns from that table as well?)  Or you want a list of categories that are associated with a paritcular product.

Comment: I want a list of products. This list should only contain products that are listed in a given category. Example: I got item1 and item2. item1 has a category "awesome item", but item2 does not. I only want item1. Though the relations is many-to-many (or HABTM if you prefer), so a category can have many products, and a product can have many categories.